# How to make this checkbox get checked properly when I click anywhere in the box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

```
<li class="vehicle-item">
 <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="take-vehicle" />
 <table summary="layout table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="3">2004 Austin Cooper</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><img src="/media/icons/tick.png" alt="" /> Drivable</td>
    <td><img src="/media/icons/cross.png" alt="" /> Convertible</td>
    <td><img src="/media/icons/cross.png" alt="" /> Modified</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
    </label>
</li>
```

As you can see, I've tried wrapping the whole thing in a `<label>` but that didn't work.

So I tried writing some jQuery instead,

```
 $('.vehicle-item').click(function() {
  var $checkbox = $(this).find('input');
  $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
 });
```

Which *does* work, except now when I click the checkbox itself, it doesn't get checked. I'm assuming because it's being checked, and then the JS unchecks it immediately. But I'm not quite sure how I would say "if I click anywhere except directly on the checkbox"?

Comment: Just as an interesting FYI, your HTML code works as is in Chrome without the jQuery code.  In FF, however, it acts as you describe.

Comment: @Gregg: I'm testing in FF first :) If any major browser fails, it's kind of useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that the event didn't come from the checkbox itself, like this:

```
$('.vehicle-item').click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName == "INPUT") return;
  var cb = $(this).find('input')[0];
  cb.checked = !cb.checked;
});
```

[You cant test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bmQZg/).

Comment: +1! The newer versions of jQuery support `.attr('checked', /* bool goes here */)`. I think this would be more elegant.

Comment: Nice! You've got a typo in there though ;) `cb` not `ch`. Works great, thanks :D

Comment: @elusive: That's what I had... except to toggle it, you have to retrieve it using `.attr` again... I think Nick's answer is actually more elegant.

Comment: @elusive - it would be much more expensive though :) Also, it's supported in jQuery as far back as I remember, possibly to 1.0.

Comment: @Nick: It actually *doesn't* work in jsFiddle for me. Works on my actual webpage though.

Comment: *"You cant test it here."* Oh yeah? Watch me! ;o)

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked in another way very recently, to do with event bubbling and stopping for certain children.

You need to ensure that the event does not fire for the checkbox itself in your case.

```
$('.vehicle-item').click(function() {
  if ($(e.target).is(':checkbox')) {
     return;
  }

  var $checkbox = $(this).find('input');
  $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```